# Get CSS computed style of elements using PHPQuery

Tags: jquery, css, phpquery

I can, of course, load a page with [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) and grab all text and URLs from all the links:

```
foreach (pq('a') as $link) {
    echo 'Description: '.pq($link)->text().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'URL: '.pq($link)->attr('href').PHP_EOL;
```

but as PHPQuery is  a PHP script, not a fully functioning web browser, I can't get the computed style for an element (e.g. it's font size) like I can in the developer console:

```
jQuery('a').eq(0).css('font-size');
"12px"
```

Has anyone managed to do this - i.e. emulate the browser and find things like font choices, position on the screen etc. - with some other PHP library or plugin?

Comment: There are a lot of factors that could influence that.  The most flexible solution would be to look int hooking into something like Webdriver.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to do this. And it's a poorly documented issue on the internet. However I'm not sure if PHPQuery is the right tool for the job anymore, since it was last updated 5 years ago. I did find a nice CSS Parser in https://github.com/radkovo/jStyleParser.git (haven't tested it yet) but it's Java. So I thought maybe it will work if I can execute Java inside a PHP script. I did some research and some say http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/ works very well. I'm going to try this sometime and I'll inform you if I'm succesful.